# Как рассчитать смещение для другой камеры?

Tags: python, opencv, web-camera, компьютерное-зрение

Имеется 2 камеры, на одной из них работает алгоритм, который детектит кружку, а на изображении с другой камеры детектора нет.
Нужно придумать алгоритм, который позволит откалибровать камеры так, чтобы на обеих камерах один и тот же объект правильно обводился боксами

пробовал откалибровать камеры с помощью `apriltag`, просто целился центром в известное место на камере без детектора, а на детекционной камере считывал координату центра `apriltag`, повторял данную манипуляцию для разных позиций тега, а потом считал медианную разность, но такой результат не удовлетворяет меня

Подскажите, какой алгоритм можно использовать для подобной калибровки? или может быть можно как нибудь высчитать матрицу трансформаций для камер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Данная задача частично не разрешима, математическими методами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пусть на схеме к1, к2 камеры соотвественно, o1, o2, o3, o4 фигуры в различные периоды времени. L - известное расстояние между камерами. Ситуация с о1 является калибровочной,- то есть угол смещения фигуры относительно центра обеих камер равен нулю, смещение о1 относительно центра первой камеры так же равен нулю. Далее ситуация с о2,- а1 угол относительно центра камеры, d2 смещение о2 относительно центра к1. Здесь мы имеем треугольник с известным углом и стороной,- то есть данных не достаточно для установления нужного угла b2. Теперь рассмотрим ситуацию с о3,- угол а3=а2, однако изменилось расстояние д3, то есть мы видим зависимость искомой величины b от изменения угла А и дальности D: чем больше Д при равном угле А, тем больше Б. Теперь рассмотрим ситуацию с о5, очевидно, что при увеличении угла А, при том же Д, угол Б уменьшается (в примере даже становится отрицательным, но мне лень перерисовывать). то есть получается пропорция типа B=A/D, но тут нужно разбираться с синусами-косинусами-радианами, чтобы решить всё правильно, но есть способ проще- вычислить угол Б для двух сосотояний и ввести константу поправки. Теперь переходим к неразрешаемой ситуации с о4- угол А1=А4, D1=D4, следовательно при приближении-удалении объекта от к1 без смещения в стороны, вторая камера будет терять объект. Очевидное решение,- вычислять угловую величину объекта не подходит,- так как объект может иметь разныи длину и ширину, и менять свою ориентацию в пространстве. Так же не подходит и поиск субизображения с к2 по тем же причинам. Видится решение в натаскивании нейронки на изображение, но это уже как из пушки по воробьям.
Однако, возможно вычислять угловой размер при нахождении объекта в стартовых координатах, затем преообразовывать его в угол.